# Search result page admin panel - display values from the result's metaboxes

Tags: plugins, posts, wp-admin

Help me please.. I have plugin for vacancy/resume/companies in the form of posts on Wordpress.

The task is to perform a standard Wordpress search for arbitrary fields inside the record.
The fields themselves are output in CMB2.

The search works by taxonomy and record name, but not by an arbitrary field.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Inside the plugin, on the companies display page, there was a search function by taxonomy and name. I added an additional field search, but without success.

```
<?php
```

class PNJobCompany extends PNJobForm
{

```
private static $_instance;

private function __construct()
{
    $this->includes();
    $this->initHook();
}

private function includes()
{
}

private function initHook()
{
    add_filter('template_include', [$this, 'templateInclude']);
    add_action('wp_loaded', [$this, 'formHandler'], 20);

    add_filter('build_company_seach_query', [$this, 'buildCompanySearchQuery'], 10, 3);
    add_filter('wp_dropdown_users', [$this, 'userDropdown']);
}


public function templateInclude($template)
{
    if (is_company_list_page()) {
        $template = pnj_get_template('company/company-list', null, false);
    }
    return $template;
}


public function formHandler()
{
    if (isset($_POST['pnj_action']) && !empty($_POST['nonce']) && wp_verify_nonce($_POST['nonce'], 'pnj')) {
        switch ($_POST['pnj_action']) {
            case 'create-company':
                $this->createHandler();
                break;
            case 'edit-company':
                $this->editHandler();
                break;
            case "delete-company":
                //$this->deleteHandler();
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

/*--The search starts here--*/

```
function searchJoinFilter($where)
{
    global $wpdb;

    if (!empty($_REQUEST['query'])) {
        $where .= ' AND ' . $wpdb->posts . '.post_title LIKE \'%' . esc_sql($wpdb->esc_like(trim($_REQUEST['query']))) . '%\'';
    }
    
    return $where;
}


/**
 * @param $posts_per_page
 * @param $paged
 * @return object WP_Query
 */
public function buildCompanySearchQuery($posts_per_page, $paged)
{
    $query = [
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'post_type' => 'company',
        'posts_per_page' => $posts_per_page,
        'paged' => $paged
    ];

    //City
    if (!empty($_REQUEST['location'])) {
        $query['tax_query'] = [
            'relation' => 'AND',
            [
                'taxonomy' => 'job-location',
                'field' => 'term_id',
                'terms' => $_REQUEST['location'],
                'compare' => 'IN'
            ]
        ];
    }
   //My search inn_company
    if (!empty($_REQUEST['company-inn'])) {
        $meta_query = [
                'key' => 'company_inn',
                'field' => 'meta_value',
                'value' => $_REQUEST['company-inn'],
                'compare' => '='
            ];
        $query['meta_query'] = $meta_query;
    }

    add_filter('posts_where', [$this, 'searchJoinFilter']);

    $result = new WP_Query($query);

    // Удаляем условие, чтобы другие вызовы WP_Query() не затрагивать
    remove_filter('posts_where', [$this, 'searchJoinFilter']);

    return $result;
}
```

/*--End search here--*/

```
public function initFields()
{
    $this->fields = [
        'post_title' => $_POST['title'] ?? '',
        'post_content' => $_POST['description'] ?? '',
        'employer_category' => $_POST['employer_category'] ?? '1',
        'company_email' => $_POST['company_email'] ?? '',
        'company_phone' => $_POST['company_phone'] ?? '',
        'company_inn' => $_POST['company_inn'] ?? '',
        'company_url' => $_POST['company_url'] ?? '',
        'company_address' => $_POST['company_address'] ?? '',

        'category' => $_POST['categories'] ?? '',
        'location' => $_POST['location'] ?? '',
        'company_form' => $_POST['company_form'] ?? '',
        'metro' => $_POST['metro'] ?? '',

    ];

}

protected function validateFields()
{
    foreach ($this->fields as $key => $value) {

        switch ($key) {
            case 'post_title':
                if ($this->fields[$key] === '')
                    $this->addError('Пожалуйста, укажите название компании');
                break;
            case 'company_inn':
                if (empty($this->fields[$key]))
                    $this->addError('Пожалуйста, введите идентификатор Федеральной налоговой службы вашей компании');
                elseif (!preg_match('/^\d{10}$/', $this->fields[$key]))
                    $this->addError('Идентификатор Федеральной налоговой службы должен состоять из 10 цифр');
                break;
            case 'company_email':
                if ($this->fields[$key] !== '' && !is_email($this->fields[$key]))
                    $this->addError('Неверный формат email');
                // TODO Реализовать проверку за занятость email, тем самым запретить регистрацию нескольких компаний на одни email
                break;
            case 'company_phone':
                if (empty($this->fields[$key])) {
                    $this->addError('Поле "Телефон" не божет быть пустым');
                }

                if (!$this->fields[$key] = format_phone($this->fields[$key])) {
                    $this->addError('Неверный формат телефона');
                }
                break;
            case 'employer_category':
                if (empty($this->fields['employer_category']))
                    $this->addError('Пожалуйста, укажите тип работодателя');
                break;
            case 'categories':
                if (empty($this->fields['categories']))
                    $this->addError('Пожалуйста, укажите отрсль компании');
                break;
            case 'location':
                if (empty($this->fields['location']))
                    $this->addError('Пожалуйста, укажите город');
                break;
        }
    }
}

public function createHandler()
{
    $user_id = get_current_user_id();

    try {

        if (empty($_POST['phone_prefix']) || empty($_POST['phone_code']) || empty($_POST['phone_number'])) {
            $this->addError('Неверно указан телефон');
        }

        $_POST['company_phone'] = $_POST['phone_prefix'] . $_POST['phone_code'] . $_POST['phone_number'] . $_POST['phone_extension'];

        $this->initFields();

        $this->validateFields();

        if (!empty($this->errors)) {
            throw new Exception(implode('<br>', $this->errors));
        }

        $company_id = wp_insert_post([
            'post_title' => sanitize_text_field($this->fields['post_title']),
            'post_type' => 'company',
            'post_status' => 'publish',
            'post_author' => $user_id,
            'post_content' => wp_kses_post($this->fields['post_content']),
            'comment_status' => 'open'
        ]);

        if (is_wp_error($company_id)) {
            throw new Exception($company_id->get_error_message());
        } else {

            $fields = ['company_url', 'company_inn', 'company_email', 'company_phone', 'employer_category', 'company_address'];
            foreach ($fields as $field) {
                if (isset($_POST[$field])) {
                    update_metadata('company', $company_id, '_' . $field, sanitize_text_field($this->fields[$field]));
                }
            }

            $taxonomies = [ 
                'category' => 'job-category',
                'company_form' => 'company-form',
                'metro' => 'job-metro'
            ];
            foreach ($taxonomies as $field => $taxonomy) {
                wp_set_post_terms($company_id, $this->fields[$field], $taxonomy);
            }

            // set logo as featured
            if (isset($_POST['company_logo'])) {
                $logo_id = $_POST['company_logo'];
                set_post_thumbnail($company_id, $logo_id);
            }

            pnj_flash_message(
                'message',
                'Новая компания успешно создана',
                'alert-success'
            );

            $redirect = pnj_get_account_link('edit-company');
            if (!empty($_REQUEST['redirect'])) {
                $redirect = $_REQUEST['redirect'];
            }
            wp_redirect($redirect);
            exit;

        }
    } catch (Exception $e) {

        pnj_flash_message('message', $e->getMessage(), 'alert-danger');

    }
}

public function editHandler()
{

    if (!isset($_POST['company_id']))
        return;

    $this->initFields();

    $user_id = get_current_user_id();
    $company_id = $_POST['company_id'];
    $company = get_post($company_id);

    try {
        $this->validateFields();

        if ($company->post_type !== 'company') {
            $this->addError('Не верный тип поста');
        }

        if ($company->post_author != $user_id && !is_user_role('administrator')) {
            $this->addError('У вас нет прав для редактирования этой компании');
        }

        if (!empty($this->errors)) {
            throw new Exception(implode('<br>', $this->errors));
        }

        wp_update_post([
            'ID' => $company_id,
            'post_title' => sanitize_text_field($this->fields['post_title']),
            'post_content' => wp_kses_post($this->fields['post_content'])
        ]);

        $fields = [
            'company_email',
            'company_phone',
            'company_inn',
            'company_url',
            'employer_category',
            'company_address'
        ];

        foreach ($fields as $field) {
            update_metadata('company', $company_id, sanitize_text_field('_' . $field), $this->fields[$field]);
        }

        $taxonomies = [
            'inn' => 'company_inn',
            'location' => 'job-location',
            'category' => 'job-category',
            'company_form' => 'company-form',
            'metro' => 'job-metro'
        ];

        wp_delete_object_term_relationships($company_id, $taxonomies);

        foreach ($taxonomies as $field => $taxonomy) {
            wp_set_post_terms($company_id, $this->fields[$field], $taxonomy);
        }


        if (isset($_POST['company_logo'])) {
            $logo_id = $_POST['company_logo'];
            if ($logo_id !== '')
                set_post_thumbnail($company_id, $logo_id);
            else
                delete_post_thumbnail($company_id);
        }

        pnj_flash_message(
            'message',
            'Компания успешно отредактирована',
            'alert-success'
        );

        $redirect = pnj_get_account_link('edit_company');
        if (!empty($_REQUEST['redirect'])) {
            $redirect = $_REQUEST['redirect'];
        }
        wp_redirect($redirect);
        exit;

    } catch (Exception $e) {
        pnj_flash_message('message', $e->getMessage(), 'alert-danger');
    }
}

/**
 * @return object PNJobCompany
 */
public static function instance()
{
    if (is_null(self::$_instance)) {
        self::$_instance = new self();
    }

    return self::$_instance;
}

public function userDropdown($output)
{
    global $post;

    if ($post->post_type === 'company') {
        $output = str_replace('</select>', '', $output);
        $users = get_users(['role' => PNJobAccount::EMPLOYER]);
        foreach ($users as $user) {
            if ($post->post_author == $user->ID) {
                continue;
            }

            $output .= '<option value="' . $user->ID . '">' . sprintf(_x('%1$s (%2$s)', 'user dropdown'), $user->display_name, $user->user_login) . '</option>';
        }
        $output .= "</select>";
    }

    return $output;
}
```

}

PNJobCompany::instance();

Comment: can you reword/rephrase your question? It's very difficult to understand and skips past a lot of explanation. For example you mentioned the search is not working and share code but never explain what the search is/does or where it comes from. You also highlighted yellow boxes in the screenshot but never explained what they were. _Use the edit link to adjust and improve your question so it's answerable._

Comment: @TomJNowell thanks, i fixed